# How to match certain TCP-based L7 protocols via acl for later use_backend?

Tags: haproxy

I have a TCP frontend exposed on port 6666, which receives traffic and must, according to the application protocol detected in the TCP payload, proxy the request to a local server capable of serving the application request.

For HTTP I got it to work, it sucessfully proxies the request to my local HTTP server when a HTTP request is received. For Telnet, SSH and FTP I couldn't make it work, so I kept the incomplete lines commented out and wanted your help composing them.

Below is a portion of my HAProxy configuration:

```
# ...
frontend tcp_sniff
    bind *:6666
    mode tcp
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s

    acl is_http req.payload(0,0) -m reg "^(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE|HEAD|OPTIONS)\s+([^ ]+)\s+HTTP\/\d+\.\d+\r\n([^\r\n]*: [^\r\n]*\r\n)*\r\n(.*)\$"
    #acl is_telnet ...
    #acl is_ssh ...
    #acl is_ftp ...

    use_backend http_backend if is_http
    #use_backend telnet_backend if is_telnet
    #use_backend ssh_backend if is_ssh
    #use_backend ftp_backend if is_ftp

backend http_backend
    mode tcp
    server http_server1 127.0.0.1:80

backend telnet_backend
    mode tcp
    server telnet_server1 127.0.0.1:23

backend ssh_backend
    mode tcp
    server ssh_server1 127.0.0.1:22

backend ftp_backend
    mode tcp
    server ftp_server1 127.0.0.1:21
```

**PS. I know it's a weird use case, but it's not for production, it's something private and peculiar I want to run on a few machines of mine, and I need help with the initial setup, I'm new to HAProxy.**